# Laravel not taking default DB_CONNECTION value from env file

Tags: linux, laravel, mongodb, amazon-web-services

i use different mongo db on both my production and development environment.

i am having different connection configurations because mongodb(production connection name) is on mongo atlas cluster so it connects using dsn however mongodb1 (development connection name) is installed locally so i connect it using host and port .

i want to use different db connections for different environments, so i have set DB_CONNECTION in env file different in both the cases.
for my production is

```
     DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
```

and for development its

```
     DB_CONNECTION=mongodb1
```

in my config/database.php file
        'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

and in the connections array i have

```
    'mongodb' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'dsn' => env('MONGO_DB_DSN'),
        'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE', 'uspl'),
        'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME', 'uspl'),
        'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD', 'unfoldingskies'),
        'options' => array(
            'db' => 'uspl'
        )
    ],

    'mongodb1' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'host' => env('MONGO_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('MONGO_DB_PORT', 27017),
        'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
        'options' => []
    ],
```

i am getting error on my development environment ->
    Database [mongodb] not configured. in file
 /var/www/html/devBackend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php on line 152

i have tried php artisan config:clear, cache:clear, composer dump-autoload but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not support MongoDB out of the box, so you need to make use of a 3rd party package to use it.

[As of this writing Laravel has the following database drivers:](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#introduction)

- MySQL 5.6+ (Version Policy)
- PostgreSQL 9.4+ (Version Policy)
- SQLite 3.8.8+
- SQL Server 2017+ (Version Policy)

A quick search on the web got me [this 3rd party package.](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB)

> ## Laravel MongoDB
>
> An Eloquent model and Query builder with support for MongoDB, using
>   the original Laravel API. This library extends the original Laravel
>   classes, so it uses exactly the same methods.

Comment: yeah i am also using the same jenssegers package, my issues is i want to use mongodb config on production environment and mongodb1 config on development environment , both configurations work fine if i use it via 'mongodb' in the connections array in database.php file, however if at the same time i have both mongodb and mongodb1 in the connections array , mongodb1 doesnt work even if the environment file have mongodb1 as DB_CONNECTION variable

Comment: And when that happens you get the error `Database [mongodb] not configured.`? What is the value of the `MONGO_DB_DATABASE` value in your environment file?

Comment: yeah exactly that's the error, its uspl in production and usplDev in development environment.

Comment: It might be a limitation of the package. It might be hardwired to use the mongodb connection name, and if you change that it doesn't work properly.

Comment: yeah but if i use customName in env DB_CONNECTION and add it into connection array it doesnt work too. Maybe we cant add custom db connections to laravel.